# Show that if $X$ admit an expected value then $\lim_{n \to \infty} nP(X\geq n+1) = 0$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $X(\Omega) \subset \mathbb{N}$.

1. Show that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}kP(X=k)=(\sum_{k=1}^{n}P(X\geq k))-nP(X\geq n+1).$$

I've been able to solve this first part :

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}kP(X=k)= P(X=1) + 2P(X=2)+3P(X=3)+\cdots  + nP(X=n)+nP(X\geq n+1)-nP(X\geq n+1)$$
$$=(P(X=1)+P(X=2)+\cdots P(X=n) +P(X\geq n+1))$$
$$+(P(X=2)+P(X=3)+\cdots P(X=n) +P(X\geq n+1))$$
$$+(P(X=3)+P(X=4)+\cdots P(X=n) +P(X\geq n+1))$$
                $$\vdots$$ 
$$+(P(X=n) +P(X\geq n+1)) - nP(X\geq n+1)$$

$$=P(X \geq 1)+P(X \geq 2)+P(X \geq 3)+\cdots P(X\geq n) - nP(X\geq n+1) =(\sum_{k=1}^{n}P(X\geq k))-nP(X\geq n+1) $$

2. Show that if X admit an expected value then $\lim_{n \to \infty} nP(X\geq n+1) = 0$.

If $X$ admits an expected value then the series $\sum_{k\geq 0}kP(X=k)$  converges absolutely

I can write that $$ \exists l\in \mathbb{R} / \sum_{k\geq 0}kP(X=k) = l$$
$$(\sum_{k\geq 1}P(X\geq k))-\lim_{n \to \infty} nP(X\geq n+1) = l$$

In order to complete this I have to prove that $\sum_{k\geq 1}P(X\geq k) = \sum_{k\geq 0}kP(X=k)$ which for me seems very weird.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done all the hard part! The only problem is that the equality that you think is weird is in fact true.

Indeed, $P(X \geq k) = \sum_{\ell = k}^\infty P(X = \ell)$, so $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty P(X \geq k) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \sum_{\ell = k}^\infty P(X = \ell)$.

For any $\ell$, the term $P(X = \ell)$ shows up in this sum when $k = 1, 2, \ldots, \ell$, and then never again, and this is precisely $\ell$ times, so we may rewrite it as $\sum_{\ell = 1}^\infty \ell P(X = \ell)$, and changing the dummy variable from $\ell$ to $k$ gives what you want.